# Generating random number as user identifier

Tags: database, random, uniqueidentifier

I have been looking at the Unique ID (UID) generation for [Aadhar (an Indian equivalent to Social Security Number)](http://uidai.gov.in/UID_PDF/Working_Papers/A_UID_Numbering_Scheme.pdf)

They generate an 11 digit random number. I am also working on an application where I need to provide unique ID to users which needs to be valid an unique throughout there lifetime (expected number of users 40-60 billion).

When looking over the web for similar schemes, I found that simplest way is to generate each  digit randomly and concatenate. So my questions are:

- Is generating each digit randomly correct way to generate such IDs
- Are there any established technique for the same ?
- What considerations one needs to take care of when designing such a scheme ? I am asking this, since I feel if the random number generation scheme doesn't ensure uniqueness. Say may be in a given time frame), then every generation needs verification. Even in that case, I believe the scheme should be able to adjust for guaranteeing that the second generated number is unique or from a different distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply store 100 billions of numbers in a database table from 000 000 000 001 to 999 999 999 999. Delete the extrem-numbers like 000...001 or 666 etc. Then generate a random number in another column (this will be the sort-order). If you need a new number, you can take it with a transaction, so you can ensure, that a number goes to only one person.

I would not generate the number on the fly... You should always check if the number already exists. At the end, the chance that generate an existing number is high. So the generation-process will take always longer and longer.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it would require me to maintain a copy in the cache and make sure that the changes are written back if the application closes/crashes or in case there are multiple servers ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the bicycle. Have a look at [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) Depends on the language you are going to use there should be some implementation for it.

Comment: But UUID is not a good number to be given to the users as ID. They may need to remember it, mention it in forms etc. Which makes UUID cumbersome.

Comment: You didn't  say that the user should remember the Id. The uuid allows you to easily assign new id  to every new record without looking into the database or any storage. If you need something for user to operate with then I would recommend to use sequential numbers in base 32.